# whether there are some books and original papers ergodic theory approach to ODE

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-dynamics

Recently I become more and more interested in the field of ergodic theory, especially in the dimension theory and thermal formalism and its applications.

People always said that most of the ideas in measurable dynamics system comes from the theory of ordinary differential equation.  But when I began to find the topics of ergodic theory approach into differential equation, I find there are few books directed related to it. I know there are many books discuss about the differential dynamics system (such as hyperbolic  theory), however most of the books did not include the ergodic theory approach.

Are there  good books and papers strongly recommend? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical reference for the relation between ergodic theory and the theory of ordinary differential equations (as it appears in classical mechanics) is:

V.I. Arnold, [Mathematical methods of classical mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387968903)